# Java breaking vs returning

Tags: java, switch-statement, boolean, break

I am using a boolean that returns true. When something like this happens:

```
public boolean t(String label, String[] arguments) {
    boolean j = false;
    if (!j) {
        return true;
    }
    return true;
}
```

However, inside of this boolean I have a `switch` statement. As you may know, you break out of switch statements usually. However I am doing something like this testing for booleans to be true or false. Would I return inside of a switch statement, or break if a boolean is false?

An example would be something like this:

```
switch (arguments.length) {
    case 0:
        if (j) return true;
        break;
    default:
        break;
}
```

Which would be more useful, exchanging return true for break, or keep it the same?

Comment: Please provide more context. Also, the `break` is unneccasary if you `return` (it is in fact unreachable).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `break` statement would terminate execution of the `switch` statement and continue in the method. A `return` statement would leave the method entirely.

It's a matter of preference, really, as to which one is better. It comes down to method design.

I would say in most cases like you have above, it would be better to directly use a `return` statement and leave the method entirely.

That said, this:

```
public boolean t(String label, String[] arguments) {
    boolean j = false;
    if (!j) {
        return true;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Can be simplified to this:

```
public boolean t(String label, String[] arguments) {   
    return true;
}
```

And if you're only checking one condition from one variable, then you don't need a `switch` statement; it's not as optimal.

> I am doing something like this testing for booleans to be true or false

You shouldn't really "test" for boolean variables to be true or false, just return them.

Comment: Actually, it can be simplified to `return true;`.

Comment: Well, yeah. I just figured `j` might mean something in the implementation.

Comment: I was just doing an example, the switch statement I am actually using has more cases than just one. How would returning a boolean do anything, if the boolean is inside of another boolean.

Answer (score 0):

Return call always returns the handler to the called function where as  break in the switch statement is to avoid checking other cases present in the switch case. If you don want your program return any values then break is sufficient else return required.